# Subset large table for use in multiple UNIONs

Tags: sql, postgresql, unpivot

Suppose I have a table with the following structure:

```
id  measure_1_actual measure_1_predicted  measure_2_actual  measure_2_predicted
1   1                0                    0                 0
2   1                1                    1                 1
3   .                .                    0                 0
```

I want to create the following table, for each ID (shown is an example for `id = 1`):

```
measure  actual   predicted
1        1        0
2        0        0
```

Here's one way I could solve this problem (I haven't tested this, but you get the general idea, I hope):

```sql
SELECT  1 AS measure, 
        measure_1_actual AS actual, 
        measure_1_predicted AS predicted 
FROM tb 
WHERE id = 1

UNION

SELECT 2 AS measure, 
       measure_2_actual AS actual, 
       measure_2_predicted AS predicted 
FROM tb WHERE id = 1
```

In reality, I have five of these "measures" and tens of millions of people -   subsetting such a large table five times for each member does not seem the most efficient way of doing this. This is a real-time API, receiving tens of requests a minute, so I think I'll need a better way of doing this. My other thought was to perhaps create a temp table/view for each member once the request is received, and then UNION based off of that subsetted table.

Does anyone have a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: I don't really understand the end goal here.  Are you trying to change the structure of your db or are you just trying to return results for a user?  How do users fit with your data model?  There are no columns obviously related to users.

Comment: your logic makes no sense, are you trying to sort by measure (rows 1, 2, etc) after splitting your  table into 2 tables?

Comment: The end goal is to provide the table in the middle (which gets converted into an HTML table) for each member. Perhaps they aren't obviously related, but each of the columns above are related to users (`id` is a unique identifier for each user, and the others are related to whether they've done "something" vs. have been predicted to).

Comment: @blacksite so as I though your ID are per user. You should created  another table structure having the a measure ID and the actual and predicted and an user column that will be related to the ID of the user. It is usually a simple inner join then between those measure table and those above, indeed on user.ID

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lateral join:

```
select t.id, v.*
from t cross join lateral
     (values (1, measure_1_actual, measure_1_predicted),
             (2, measure_2_actual, measure_2_predicted)
     ) v(measure, actual, predicted);
```

Lateral joins were introduced in Postgres 9.4.  You can read about them in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html).

Comment: Indeed. What I only wrote "theoretically" in the comment, except the "cross join".